# display the previous month name and year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Here i used one label to display the current month with year. and it have one button on side to move to previous month. when user press side button it should display the previous month .

i did only to show the present month. but not able to move and display the previous month in same label.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy";
NSString * yearString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",monthString,yearString];
```

Here my button press method :

```
- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)rightBtn:(id)sender {
}
```

So at `normal`, when `view load` it should display `December, 2015`. And when user press `leftbutton` that `datelabel` should display `november,2015`. And too when user press `right button` from `november month` it should display `december, 2015`

I m very confused. Please help me to solve, this is my first question.Help me.Thanks  !

Comment: I'd recommend to use `NSDateComponents` (from current date, then -1 month to it) to get the previous month `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NSDateComponents`

```
- (IBAction)rightBtn:(id)sender 
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:datelabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    datelabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];

}
```

and the same thing for left button

```
- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender 
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:datelabel.text];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setMonth:-1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate options:0];

    datelabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
}
```

Comment: ohh man awesome move. Thanks fro help, sure it will help me to learn.

Comment: Don't convert back and forwards from view text, that's a terrible design and architecture

Comment: one more question, in my above post. i entered some code in view did load. its working fine. that my viewdidload code is ok or should i need to change .

Comment: @Wain I don't see how this could be done in an other way, maybe you can help me I use this method a lot.

Comment: @joseph I need to see more of your code, maybe another question ?

Comment: My answer explains. You are using a view to store data, which is against MVC and sound design. You need a date in your date model that is your truth and you manipulate as a result of UI interaction

Comment: @maetsoh didn get you. you want me to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance variable to store the current date. When the view is loaded set it to `[NSDate date]`. Update your current code so it can be run at any time and uses the instance variable date to update the labels.

Once you've done that, change the setup code so you get the current date and use `NSDateComponents` to remove the day and time from the date so the date you store in the instance variable is the first day of the month. Test to make sure that works and looks the same to the user.

Now your left and right buttons can use date components to add or remove a month from the instance variable date and then update the labels.

Comment: Oh I see this is better, @joseph you need to make an instance variable in your implementation for example `@implementation yourViewController { NSDate *myDate`; } or in your .m or .h files then just follow @Wain's answer, and use this variable in your  `rightBtn`    `leftBtn ` methods instead of datelabel.txt.